# Extract all devices off TERA-WURFL database

Tags: php, mobile-website, wurfl

Is there anyway I could extract all the devices (and their attributes) inside the TERA-WURFL mysql database with PHP? I need to show a list of supported devices in my web app.

There seems to be scant info on the internets on how to do this - can this be done?

Comment: how do you mean? simply connecting to database and listing all devices work for you?

Comment: No, attempting to query the Tera-WURFL DB directly doesn't work. Seems tera-wurfl api does some work after querying the UA - because the DB does not see to have all the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tera-wurlf database use wurlf XML, you can reimport XML version available : http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/wurfl/WURFL/latest/wurfl-latest.zip